# Hiding AG Grid column filter popup after filter is applied - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

So I'm working on a React app and I have a table that I applied AG Grid to. I used the filter: "agTextColumnFilter" and filter: "adDateColumnFilter" for a few columns but I wanted to know if there is a way to close/hide the filter popup once I click the "Apply Filter..." button instead of having to click somewhere else on the page to get rid of it.

I tried looking through the AG Grid documentations but couldn't figure out if there's actually a solution to my question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> closeOnApply: If the Apply button is present, the filter popup will be closed immediately when the Apply or Reset button is clicked if this is set to true.

Example usage

```
const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    {
      field: 'athlete',
      filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {
        buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
        closeOnApply: true,
      },
    },
]);
```

Here's the link

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/react/filter-text/